# Android SQLite crashes after trying retrieving data from it

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey everyone. I'm kinda new to android programming so please bear with me. I'm having some problems with retrieving records from the db. Basically, all I want to do is to store latitudes and longitudes which GPS positioning functions outputs and display them in a list using ListActivity on different tab later on. This is how the code for my DBAdapter helper class looks like:

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    public static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "coords";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "coordsStorage";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table coordsStorage (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "latitude integer not null, longitude integer not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertCoords(int latitude, int longitude) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_LATITUDE,
                KEY_LONGITUDE}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_LATITUDE, 
                        KEY_LONGITUDE}, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    /*public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, int latitude, 
    int longitude) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
        args.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }*/
}
```

Now my question is - am I doing something wrong here? If yes could someone please tell me what? And how I should retrieve the records in organised list manner? Help would be greatly appreciated!!

This are the error it throws:

```
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276): Error inserting latitude=0 longitude=0
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: coordsStorage: , while compiling: INSERT INTO coordsStorage(latitude, longitude) VALUES(?, ?);
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:925)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1300)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1173)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at tabs.app.DBAdapter.insertCoords(DBAdapter.java:81)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at tabs.app.Tribocracy$1.onClick(Tribocracy.java:118)
06-06 14:49:32.434: ERROR/Database(276):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
```

and then when I'm trying to retrieve it it throws this:

```
06-06 14:49:52.734: INFO/Process(51): Sending signal. PID: 276 SIG: 3
06-06 14:49:52.734: INFO/dalvikvm(276): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-06 14:49:52.734: ERROR/dalvikvm(276): Unable to open stack trace file /data/anr/traces.txt': 
Permission denied
```

Comment: What actually happens? The title says "Crashes" - does the app force close? If so, what does it say in the logs (use `adb logcat`)?

Comment: First of all, thx Chris for reply. I should have mentioned that I want to insert record into db on a click of a button so I'm invoking the insertCoords like this: 

   db.open();        
          db.insertCoords(
            intLatitude,
            intLongitude
            );        
          db.close();

and it doesn't crash (aka force close) so I assume it inserts the record into db but when I'm trying to retrieve it the app is doin Force Close. And sorry for asking this (I'm a a complete newbie) but how and where can I access the error log?

Comment: In future, please refrain from using an answer to contact a user who has provided an answer.  You can leave a comment on their answer, or you can edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the table doesn't exist for some reason.

You may want to try increasing your version number, to force an upgrade; if the database itself exists then the onCreate method won't be called - increasing the version will force onUpgrade to be called, and your implementation drops the table and recreates it. This should either fix your error, or give you a new error to work with!

Answer (score 0):

Change your Latitude and Longitude datatypes to double

```
double Latitude;
double Longitude;
```